# Unable to modify circles after appending (inner data)

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have appended circles to the centroids of the arcs in my custom spectrum display visual as follows:

```js
var margins = {top:200, bottom:50, left:200, right:100};

var height = 600;
var width = 900;

var totalWidth = width+margins.left+margins.right;
var totalHeight = height+margins.top+margins.bottom;

var svg = d3.select('body')
.append('svg')
.attr('width', totalWidth)
.attr('height', totalHeight);

var graphGroup = svg.append('g')
.attr('transform', "translate("+margins.left+","+margins.top+")");

var pie = d3.pie()
.startAngle(-Math.PI/1.3)
.endAngle(Math.PI/1.3);

var outerRadius = 50;
var innerRadius = 25;

var fullArray = [
  [0,0,0,0,0,0],
  [1,2,0,4,0,6],
  [0,0,0,4,0,0],
  [0,0,0,0,0,0],
  [1,2,0,4,0,0],
  [0,0,0,0,0,0],
  [1,2,3,4,5,6],
  [0,0,0,0,0,0],
  [0,0,0,4,0,0],
  [0,0,0,0,0,0],
  [0,0,0,0,0,0],
  [0,0,0,0,0,0],
  [0,0,0,0,0,0],
  [0,0,0,0,0,0]
];

var cArray = pie(d3.range(6).map(()=>1));

cArray.forEach(function(item,i) {
  item.licenses = fullArray[i];
});

var categories = 6;
var cData = d3.range(categories).map(()=>1);

var cbirc = 4;
var cbircProto = d3.range(cbirc).map(()=>1);
var cbircProto2 = pie(cbircProto);

var layers = 14;

var cbircData = d3.range(cbirc).map(()=>cbircProto2);

var columns = 5;

var spacing = 220;

var vSpacing =250;

var arc = d3.arc()
  .innerRadius(innerRadius)
  .outerRadius(outerRadius);

var arc2 = d3.arc()
  .innerRadius(50)
  .outerRadius(75);

var pieG = graphGroup.selectAll(null)
.data(cArray)
.enter()
.append('g');

var pieG2 = graphGroup.selectAll(null)
.data(cbircData[0])
.enter()
.append('g');

var colorMap = {
  0:'none',
  1:'#95b3d7',
  2:'#d9d9d9',
  3:'#f6d18b',
  4:'#e4a733',
  5:'#a6a6a6',
  6:"#003366"
};

for (var k = 0; k < 15; k++) {

var thisClass = 'bank'+String(k);
var thisClass2 = 'circ'+String(k);
var horSpace = (k % columns) * spacing;

var vertSpace = ~~((k / columns)) * vSpacing;

pieG.data(cArray[k]);

pieG.append('path')
.attr('d', arc)
.attr('class', thisClass)
.style('stroke', '#003366')
.style('stroke-width', "2px")
.style('fill', "#fff");


pieG.append('circle')
.attr('class', thisClass2)
.attr('cx', function(d) {return arc.centroid(d)[0] + horSpace;})
.attr('cy', function(d) {return arc.centroid(d)[1]+ vertSpace;})
.attr('r', 3);

pieG.selectAll('.'+thisClass2)
  .data(function(d) { return [d.licenses]
  })
  .style('fill', function(d,i) { return colorMap[d]});

pieG2.append('path')
.attr('d', arc2)
.attr('class', thisClass)
.style('stroke', '#003366')
.style('stroke-width', "2px")
.style('fill', "#fff");

var horSpace = (k % columns) * spacing;

var vertSpace = ~~((k / columns)) * vSpacing;

d3.selectAll('.'+thisClass).attr('transform', "translate("+horSpace+","+vertSpace+")");

}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
```

The logic for the fills of the circles within the arcs of the spectrum display are stored in `fullArray`. As seen in the snippet, I spliced `fullArray` into the pie data as an external property, thinking it would be easy to access later on.

However, as seen in the output, the circles are not changing color after I tried setting the `.style('fill')` using a specific selection. I would have liked to not use the inner data structure, but there seems to be no way to create the arcs and append numeric color logic in one fell swoop.

On paper, (and in the console log), all the data is being bound correctly to the svg elements, but all the circles appear black. So, I wonder why can't I color code via `colorMap`.

### Question

How to design my data structure so that I have both arc geometry (for the paths) and ordinal color coding logic (for circles placed at the arc centroids) available?

**Note:** To be clear, the desired outcome is for the circles to have a fill logic based on `colorMap` for each item in `fullArray` (which is an array of arrays). Aside from several arrays that are all `0`'s, the others are varied, and thus most spectrum displays should have different numbers of circles in different arcs . This is an obvious giveaway suggesting that my code in its current form is flawed (as they all look the same). Values with `0` should have a fill of `'none'` and values 1-6 follow `colorMap` accordingly.

Comment: I managed to change the colors. https://jsfiddle.net/4oe30x89/. I don't think it's in the way you want to but you can see where the problem comes from. `d` is an array, (you can debug it). You're passing `colorMap[d]` so it doesn't do anything. Maybe you want to pass something else?

Comment: @VladimirBogomolov Thanks for attempting this, very helpful. I also managed to get some basic color coding on previous iterations, but as you note, the actual logic of `fullArray` is not being applied. Since `.data()` is an array, I would presume `d` would be an item in that array. But since `d` is an array, it would appear I have a faulty data structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood correctly, this is your desired output?:

I did it by making a couple of small modifications to your code. (But read my comments below on how I would approach it in general).

[image]

Full demo: https://jsfiddle.net/alexander_L/4bjtkqev/11/

Also below:

```js
var margins = {top:200, bottom:50, left:200, right:100};

var height = 600;
var width = 900;

var totalWidth = width+margins.left+margins.right;
var totalHeight = height+margins.top+margins.bottom;

var svg = d3.select('body')
.append('svg')
.attr('width', totalWidth)
.attr('height', totalHeight);

var graphGroup = svg.append('g')
.attr('transform', "translate("+margins.left+","+margins.top+")");

var pie = d3.pie()
.startAngle(-Math.PI/1.3)
.endAngle(Math.PI/1.3);

var outerRadius = 50;
var innerRadius = 25;

var fullArray = [
  [0,0,0,0,0,0],
  [1,2,0,4,0,6],
  [0,0,0,4,0,0],
  [0,0,0,0,0,0],
  [1,2,0,4,0,0],
  [0,0,0,0,0,0],
  [1,2,3,4,5,6],
  [0,0,0,0,0,0],
  [0,0,0,4,0,0],
  [0,0,0,0,0,0],
  [0,0,0,0,0,0],
  [0,0,0,0,0,0],
  [0,0,0,0,0,0],
  [0,0,0,0,0,0]
];

var cArray = pie(d3.range(6).map(()=>1));

cArray.forEach(function(item,i) {
  item.licenses = fullArray[0];
});

var categories = 6;
var cData = d3.range(categories).map(()=>1);
var cbirc = 4;
var cbircProto = d3.range(cbirc).map(()=>1);
var cbircProto2 = pie(cbircProto);
var layers = 14;
var cbircData = d3.range(cbirc).map(()=>cbircProto2);
var columns = 5;
var spacing = 220;
var vSpacing =250;

//console.log(cArray)

var arc = d3.arc()
  .innerRadius(innerRadius)
  .outerRadius(outerRadius);

var arc2 = d3.arc()
  .innerRadius(50)
  .outerRadius(75);

var pieG = graphGroup.selectAll(null)
.data(cArray)
.enter()
.append('g')
.attr('class', 'pieG');

var pieG2 = graphGroup.selectAll(null)
.data(cbircData[0])
.enter()
.append('g')
.attr('class', 'pieG2');

var colorMap = {
  0:'none',
  1:'#95b3d7',
  2:'#d9d9d9',
  3:'#f6d18b',
  4:'#e4a733',
  5:'#a6a6a6',
  6:"#003366"
};

for (var k = 0; k < 14; k++) {

var thisClass = 'bank'+String(k);
var thisClass2 = 'circ'+String(k);
var horSpace = (k % columns) * spacing;

var vertSpace = ~~((k / columns)) * vSpacing;

cArray.forEach(function(item,i) {
    //console.log(k, fullArray[k])
  item.licenses = fullArray[k];
});
//pieG.data(cArray);
//console.log(k,cArray)

pieG.append('path')
.attr('d', arc)
.attr('class', thisClass)
.style('stroke', '#003366')
.style('stroke-width', "2px")
.style('fill', "#fff");


pieG.append('circle')
.attr('class', thisClass2)
.attr('cx', function(d,i) { return arc.centroid(d)[0] + horSpace;})
.attr('cy', function(d) {return arc.centroid(d)[1]+ vertSpace;})
.attr('r', 3)
.style('fill', function(d,i) {/*console.log(i,d)*/;return colorMap[d.licenses[i]]});

pieG2.append('path')
.attr('d', arc2)
.attr('class', thisClass)
.style('stroke', '#003366')
.style('stroke-width', "2px")
.style('fill', "#fff");

var horSpace = (k % columns) * spacing;

var vertSpace = ~~((k / columns)) * vSpacing;

d3.selectAll('.'+thisClass).attr('transform', "translate("+horSpace+","+vertSpace+")");

}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
```

However, the use of a for loop is not really a "classical" use of d3.js.

I think we should reformat your code to exclude that. If I have time, I will try to do that later (and edit this answer to include that).

I would bind `<g></g>` tags to each item (arr) of your `fullArray` (14 items, index 0 to 13) data and then inside each of these `<g></g>` tags, I would then bind again (nested) to each val of the item (arr). Then I would append my inner paths and circles etc. I would then bind (nested) to the `<g></g>` tags again to append also (in a separate code block) the outer arcs. If this is always 4, we can generate this on the fly similar to how you did.

Alternatively (and my preference), you could make your `fullArray` an array of objects, each with all info inside to generate the inner and outer arcs and make it flexible to change later to allow an item with 3 inner-arcs and 5 outer-arcs, for example.

Your initial data should probably look like this (you could also add `{x: 0, y: 0}` values to each object, or you can calculate them on the fly based on similar logic to what you already have in your for-loop:

```js
var fullArray = [
  {inner: [0,0,0,0,0,0], outer: 4},
  {inner: [1,2,0,4,0,6], outer: 4},
  {inner: [0,0,0,4,0,0], outer: 4},
  {inner: [0,0,0,0,0,0], outer: 4},
  {inner: [1,2,0,4,0,0], outer: 4},
  {inner: [0,0,0,0,0,0], outer: 4},
  {inner: [1,2,3,4,5,6], outer: 4},
  {inner: [0,0,0,0,0,0], outer: 4},
  {inner: [0,0,0,4,0,0], outer: 4},
  {inner: [0,0,0,0,0,0], outer: 4},
  {inner: [0,0,0,0,0,0], outer: 4},
  {inner: [0,0,0,0,0,0], outer: 4},
  {inner: [0,0,0,0,0,0], outer: 4},
  {inner: [0,0,0,0,0,0], outer: 4},
];
```

Any questions, let me know.

**Update - alternative approach:**

Binding the `<g></g>` tags to the array of objects (data structure above) and then doing nested data binding for each `<g></g>` tag.

Full demo: https://jsfiddle.net/alexander_L/1zkgdnw7/3/

Also below:

```js
var margins = {top:80, bottom:80, left:80, right:80};
var height = 600;
var width = 900;
var totalWidth = width+margins.left+margins.right;
var totalHeight = height+margins.top+margins.bottom;

var svg = d3.select('body')
  .append('svg')
  .attr('width', totalWidth)
  .attr('height', totalHeight);

var graphGroup = svg.append('g')
.attr('transform', "translate("+margins.left+","+margins.top+")");

var pie = d3.pie()
  .startAngle(-Math.PI/1.3)
  .endAngle(Math.PI/1.3);

var innerRadius = 25;
var midRadius = 50;
var outerRadius = 70;
var columns = 5;
var spacing = 220;
var vSpacing = 250;

var fullArray = [
  {inner: [0,0,0,0,0,0], outer: 4},
  {inner: [1,2,0,4,0,6], outer: 4},
  {inner: [0,0,0,4,0,0], outer: 4},
  {inner: [0,0,0,0,0,0], outer: 4},
  {inner: [1,2,0,4,0,0], outer: 4},
  {inner: [0,0,0,0,0,0], outer: 4},
  {inner: [1,2,3,4,5,6], outer: 4},
  {inner: [0,0,0,0,0,0], outer: 4},
  {inner: [0,0,0,4,0,0], outer: 4},
  {inner: [0,0,0,0,0,0], outer: 4},
  {inner: [0,0,0,0,0,0], outer: 4},
  {inner: [0,0,0,0,0,0], outer: 4},
  {inner: [0,0,0,0,0,0], outer: 4},
  {inner: [0,0,0,0,0,0], outer: 4},
];

var colorMap = {
  0:'none',
  1:'#95b3d7',
  2:'#d9d9d9',
  3:'#f6d18b',
  4:'#e4a733',
  5:'#a6a6a6',
  6:"#003366"
};

var arc = d3.arc()
  .innerRadius(innerRadius)
  .outerRadius(midRadius);

var arc2 = d3.arc()
  .innerRadius(midRadius)
  .outerRadius(outerRadius);

var pieG = graphGroup.selectAll('.pieG')
  .data(fullArray)
  .enter()
  .append('g')
  .attr('class', 'pieG')
  .attr('id', (d,i) => 'pieG' + i)
  .attr('transform', (d,k) => {
    var horSpace = (k % columns) * spacing;
    var vertSpace = ~~((k / columns)) * vSpacing;
    return "translate("+horSpace+","+vertSpace+")";
  });

pieG.selectAll('.pathInner')
  .data(d => pie(d.inner.map(e => 1)))
  .enter()
  .append('path')
  .attr('d', d => arc(d))
  .attr('class', 'pathInner')
  .style('stroke', '#003366')
  .style('stroke-width', "2px")
  .style('fill', "#fff");
          
pieG.selectAll('.circleInner')
  .data(d => {
    const data = pie(d.inner.map(e => 1));
    return data.map((e,i) => {
      e.value = d.inner[i];
      return e;
    })
  })
  .enter()
  .append('circle')
  .attr('class', 'circleInner')
  .attr('cx', d => arc.centroid(d)[0])
  .attr('cy', d => arc.centroid(d)[1])
  .attr('r', 3)
  .style('fill', d => colorMap[d.value]);

pieG.selectAll('.pathOuter')
  .data(d => pie(d3.range(d.outer).map(e => 1)))
  .enter()
  .append('path')
  .attr('d', arc2)
  .attr('class', 'pathOuter')
  .style('stroke', '#003366')
  .style('stroke-width', "2px")
  .style('fill', "#fff");
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
```

Same output:

[image]